# pandas pivot table col name and values column name to be removed

Tags: python, pandas

I have an input df

```
{'Name': {0: 'AA',1: 'BB',2: 'CC',3: 'DD',4: 'EE',5: 'AA',6: 'EE',7: 'FF'},
 'WK': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: 2, 5: 3, 6: 4, 7: 5},
 'LG': {0: 'qwe',1: 'wer',2: 'sff',3: 'err',4: 'wer',5: 'rtt',6: 'eww',7'tyy'}}
```

[image]

i did the below

```
df1=pd.pivot_table(dfp,values=['LG'],index='Name',columns='WK',aggfunc='count').fillna(0)
```

[image]

i want the output as below .. like WK and LG should not appear and WK values as columns

[image]

Columns should be like Name 1 2 3 4 5

Comment: Can you post `df.to_dict()` to the question please. It's very tedious to transcribe images manually.

Comment: Do you want me to put inputs as text instead of image ? actually it is sample

Comment: @Ch3steR, I have added .. pls check

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It just takes a bit of post processing on the column and index names. Drop the "LG" level (or just pass it as a string instead of a list, since you're only using one), drop the "WK" as the column level name. If you want 'Name' as index instead of column, take out the `.reset_index()`

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name':"AA,BB,CC,DD,EE,AA,EE,FF".split(','), 'WK':[1,2,3,4,2,3,4,5], 'LG':np.ones(8)})

df1=pd.pivot_table(df,values=['LG'],index='Name',columns='WK',aggfunc='count').fillna(0)

#~ Drop the LG, make Name into a columns, then drop WK as column level name
df1 = df1.droplevel(0,axis=1).reset_index().rename_axis(columns=None)

      Name    1    2    3    4    5
#~    0   AA  1.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0
#~    1   BB  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
#~    2   CC  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0
#~    3   DD  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0
#~    4   EE  0.0  1.0  0.0  1.0  0.0
#~    5   FF  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try this. Pass `'LG'` as `str` instead of `list`.

```
(df.pivot_table(index='Name', columns='WK', values='LG', aggfunc = 'count', fill_value=0).
    rename_axis(index=None, columns=None))

    1  2  3  4  5
AA  1  0  1  0  0
BB  0  1  0  0  0
CC  0  0  1  0  0
DD  0  0  0  1  0
EE  0  1  0  1  0
FF  0  0  0  0  1
```

Or

```
(df.pivot_table(index='Name', columns='WK', aggfunc = 'size', fill_value=0).
    rename_axis(index=None, columns=None))
```

Or

You can use [`pd.crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html)

```
pd.crosstab(index = df['Name'], columns = df['WK']).rename_axis(index=None, columns=None)

    1  2  3  4  5
AA  1  0  1  0  0
BB  0  1  0  0  0
CC  0  0  1  0  0
DD  0  0  0  1  0
EE  0  1  0  1  0
FF  0  0  0  0  1
```

Or

Using [`GroupBy.size`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html#pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size) with [`df.unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html)

```
df.groupby(['Name', 'WK']).size().unstack(fill_value=0)

WK    1  2  3  4  5
Name
AA    1  0  1  0  0
BB    0  1  0  0  0
CC    0  0  1  0  0
DD    0  0  0  1  0
EE    0  1  0  1  0
FF    0  0  0  0  1
```

- If you only want to suppress *column's* name and not *index's* name remove `index=None` from [`.rename_axis`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html)